# How to decode a nested json into a List[Object] using Circe in Scala

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have a json that looks somewhat like this:

```json
{
    "results": {
        "result_1": {
            "text": "abc"
        },
        "result_2": {
            "text": "def"
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to decode it to a case class that looks like:

```
case class Results(results: List[SingleResult])

case class SingleResult(text: String)
```

I wish to write a decoder for this but my current decoder isn't compiling. It looks like this:

```
implicit val singleResultDecoder: Decoder[SingleResult] = deriveDecoder[SingleResult]
implicit val ResultsDecoder: Decoder[Results] = new Decoder[Results] {
    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Results] = {
        for {
            results <- c.keys.map(_.map(k => c.downField(k).as[SingleResult]).toList)
        } yield Results(results = results)
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
Type mismatch : 
Required: scala.List[SingleResult]
Found: scala.List[Result[SingleResult]]
```

Any directions on how to fix the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing few things here. In your json, you don't have a list, as you are trying to read it. You have a map. Therefore we need to have our `Decoder` accordingly:

```
implicit val ResultsDecoder: Decoder[Results] = new Decoder[Results] {
  override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Results] = {
    for {
      results <- c.downField("results").as[Map[String, SingleResult]]
    } yield Results(results = results.values.toList)
  }
}
```

Then calling:

```
val decodedFoo = circe.jawn.decode[Results](jsonString)
println(decodedFoo)
```

results in:

```
Right(Results(List(SingleResult(abc), SingleResult(def))))
```

Code run in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/Bgvy6uldRbqvGPxEdq0g9g/1).